# unfortunately app has stopped error - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

when i run my project in eclipse, i get this error: "unfortunately app has stopped" and i am unable to run my project. please help me solving this issue. below are my logcat and code

**LogCat:**

```
03-16 15:01:49.654: D/AndroidRuntime(1238): Shutting down VM
03-16 15:01:49.654: W/dalvikvm(1238): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a2cba8)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): Process: com.test.myfirstapp, PID: 1238
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.myfirstapp/com.test.myfirstapp.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.myfirstapp.ExampleActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.myfirstapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.myfirstapp-1, /system/lib]]
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.myfirstapp.ExampleActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.myfirstapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.myfirstapp-1, /system/lib]]
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-16 15:01:49.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     ... 11 more
03-16 15:01:53.934: I/Process(1238): Sending signal. PID: 1238 SIG: 9
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.test.myfirstapp.ExampleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.18"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u hv not declared the class in manifest

Comment: I've posted the manifest there. Not sure exactly what I'm missing.

Comment: what is ur activity name?

Comment: I just posted it i think

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner myself, but:

```
activity android:name="com.test.myfirstapp.ExampleActivity"
```

on the 15th line of your code specifies that android should start ExampleActivity. Are you sure this is the name of your main activity? Because if this is the default build from eclipse, you should have MainActivity.

Start a new project in eclipse and see how the default xml is there